# add rule to jQuery validate from code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I know that to add a validator with jQuery you would do something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    <%=txtUserName.UniqueID %>: {
                    maxlength: 5,
}
```

But how would I add to the rules from the code behind, say for example add the required rule to the textbox.

How would I go about doing that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve this by building up a string query with the StringBuilder then registering the script on the page with :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to produce the entire rules parameter using a function in the code behind, so for example on the page you would have:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form1").validate(<%=GetValidationRules()%>);
```

and then add a function in the code behind, GetValidationRules that returns the parameter containing the rules for all controls to be validated.

Answer (score 0):

To add a rule to an element you can try

```
$("#input_ID").rules("add", "required"); // input_ID is element's id
```

Above line will add the `required` rule to an element with id `input_ID`. But in this case you have to call `$("#form1").validate();` first and you have it already. Also you can use

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
   },
   messages: {
       name: "Please specify your name",
       email: {
           required: "We need your email address to contact you",
           email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
        }
    }
});
```

Above code specifies a `name` element as `required` and an `email` element as `required` and a valid email address. A single message is specified for the `name` element, and two messages for `email`. Here, `name` and `email` are name of two elements.

[Read More](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Plugin_methods).

Comment: Thanks for this but i want to add a rule from the code behind, thats my goal.

Comment: Okay, basically I want to dynamically create a control, and then create a rule for the control to be a required field. Thats basically what I want to do.